# Event registration expires - why?

Tags: civievent, registration

Question from Civi newbie:

I'm testing the event registration process, live.  Why do I get this message:

"Your pending event registration for Restoring Oceans, Restoring Climate has expired because you did not confirm your registration."

I don't know what "confirm" means. Registration was completed and charged with credit card via Paypal standard. I received no e-mail asking for any kind of confirmation.

IOW, it seems to me that it shouldn't have expired.

Thanks!

Adam

Answer (score 5):

The message is a little misleading. This email is generated if you've got the field "Pending participant expiration (hours)" set on the "Online Registration" tab of your event configuration. The help text for this field states:

> Time limit in hours for confirming/finishing registration by
>   participants with any of the pending statuses. Enter 0 (or leave
>   empty) to disable this feature.

If you don't have participant approval or waitlisting enabled for your event, then the likely cause is that your PayPal transactions are getting stuck in a pending state. You've probably seen the "Pending (Incomplete Transaction)" status on contributions in your database. Have a look in PayPal to see if the funds are actually going through. If they are, you probably have a config problem keeping PayPal from pinging CiviCRM to let it know that the transaction was successful. Is your notification URL set in PayPal?